# how to get date diff in months for datetime, i ve tried datediff but i got errors

Tags: php, date, datetime

```
$date1 = new DateTime("2012-12-15 14:11:42");
$date2 = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
$month =  $date1->diff(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
echo $month->m;
```

Instead of displaying the difference what i get is the warning below
Warning: DateTime::diff() expects parameter 1 to be DateTime, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\giftcodex\test.php on line 9

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\giftcodex\test.php on line 10

Answer (score 0):

here is the mistake rather of giving it a string generated by `date('Y-m-d H:i:s')` give it a `DateTime` object `$date2`

```
$month =  $date1->diff($date2);
echo $month->format('%m')
```

check the docs here http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) from the PHP Manual.

The date_diff is a PHP feature which can help you in this regard, as given below.

```
$interval = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%m months');
```

Answer (score 0):

Method `->diff()` will as first parameter accept DateTime object, not string.

Change:

```php
$month =  $date1->diff(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
```

to:

```php
$month =  $date1->diff($date2);
```

---

To get full month difference between 2 dates, you will also need to add years*12:

```php
$date1  = new DateTime("2012-12-15 14:11:42");
$date2  = new DateTime("now");
$diff   = $date1->diff($date2);
$months = $diff->m + $diff->y * 12;
```